# Aggregate values of next column if current column is not null

Tags: r

```
Item  Price  Discounted_price
A     5.70        4.00
B     4.50        NA
C     5.67        3.50
D     3.23        2.75
E     1.24        NA
F     4.25        NA
```

I have this dataset where i would like to show the price of each item but the catch is that if discounted_price is not NA, the discounted_price will be taken instead. May i know how can i start in R?

```
Item Price 
A     4.00
B     4.50 
C     3.50 
D     2.75 
E     1.24 
F     4.25
```

Comment: `df$Price <- dplyr::coalesce(df$Discounted_price, df$Price)`

Answer (score 0):

data['Price'] = np.where(data["Discounted_price"] < data["Price"], data["Discounted_price"], data["Price"])

data is the dataframe in which your data is stored.
This is for python.